# convert one date format to another

Tags: php

I need help to convert a formatted date format as stated below:

How can I convert 2010-02-06 14:44:43 to  dd/mm/yyyy

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-02-06 14:44:43');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Output:-

> 06/02/2010

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/datetime)

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer? It doesn't answer the question. A unix timestamp looks like `1390835286.45`, not `2010-02-06 14:44:43`. -1 for that.

Comment: @MikeS. Read the question; the OP thinks `2010-02-06 14:44:43` is a unix timestamp. Anyway, why ask me? I didn't accept it, I just answered the question that was asked rather than just reading the title and jumping to conclusions as so many people here seem to do.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean direct this at you. more of a general "that's not a timestamp" sorta thing. But, then again, OP never said anything about unix timestamp. So I'm way off base.

Answer (score 3):

Great place to start for this type of general information, php docs, specifically related to your date format question: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

-- Edit --

Answer with substr() forced me to do the work... using substr() to format a date is not the best option as PHP has built-in functions for that.

```
var_dump(date('d/m/Y', strtotime('2010-02-06 14:44:43')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$time = strtotime('2010-02-06 14:44:43');
echo date('d/m/Y',$time);
?>
```

Comment: This is an incorrect response. OP wanted Unix to date, not vice versa.

Comment: This isn't vice-versa! And OP wanted to specifically convert that particular string type to the other.

Comment: My apologies. I had been searching on unix timestamp stuff all day and my brain was playing tricks on me. The OP doesn't even mention timestamps.